# redux: Performance modifying property of an object in array using immutable approach. Pros and cons

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux, immutability

In my basic understanding about the functional programming way and the way that I need generate the next state in redux when a specific array's change, i've been trying this approach for modify a todo item by index in a todo list:

```
const toggleSelectedTodo = (todos, selectedIndex) => {
    return todos.map((todo, index) => (
        { ...todo, completed: index === selectedIndex ? !todo.completed : todo.completed  }
    ))
}


export default function reducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        case "TOGGLE_SELECTED":
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: toggleSelectedTodo(state.todos, action.index)
            }  
        ...

        default:
              return state
    }
}
```

So, my idea it's that I need re-map the all the todo item objects maintaining their values except for the target item. But, I think that isn`t performant and I'm worry about the performance for large arrays and the worst case.

**Do you know a better strategies for modify a object property inside an array or this it's the right way for do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only modify the object with selected index. There's no need to use the spread operator for EVERY object in the array. That can be the potential performance bottleneck. To avoid that your `toggleSelectedTodo` function should look like this:

```
const toggleSelectedTodo = (todos, selectedIndex) => {
    return todos.map((todo, index) => {
        if(index === selectedIndex) {
          return { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed  }
        }
        return todo
    })
}
```

Besides that you shouldn't worry about the performance unless you're processing thousands of items.

Comment: Definitely don't worry about performance until it's actually a problem. Then and, only then, should you use some profiling tools to figure out why things are slow.